# Best Practice for when to implement Ajax?

Tags: ajax

In this [Microsoft tutorial](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/#MVC_SampleApp) they implement Ajax in the final step: "Step 7. Implement Ajax"

I know it's only a tutorial so it's kept simple but I have seen this idea elsewhere too, build the app and then sprinkle ajax where appropriate.

I implement ajax as I go but I am wondering what people feel is a best practice concerning this.  Is it best to throw ajax on at the end or should you be implementing it as you go?  Anyone ran into trouble one way or another?

Comment: lots of previous questions on this subject.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your core user interactions will rely on Ajax (e.g., Google Docs), then you should implement those bits early.

Otherwise, if your core interactions rely instead on reliably storing and retrieving data, add Ajax last. This way, you force yourself and your team to test your app's behavior as if JavaScript were unavailable on your user's browser. In this instance, Ajax would be an extra layer of user interface goodness.

Comment: As usual, never an absolute rule, sometimes I forget that.  Thank you Ron.

Answer (score 3):

The argument for doing AJAX last is that you are much more likely to develop a site that degrades gracefully if you get it working without AJAX first.

This does not matter to some people--I've seen (internal) sites designed for a specific *version* of a specific browser with a definite set of features turned on.  But if it matters to you, it is much easier to add AJAX to a site that works well without it than it is to remove AJAX from a site that depends on it from the start.

Answer (score 2):

What does 'as you go' mean ? I start with a design, and so it's very clear what the final product will be. So, yes, you need to know where the ajax stuff happens right from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

I do it as I go, where it makes sense.  It's rare that we have a complete design spec from day 1, so you have to make a descision sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the fact that you'd expect the requirement for Ajax to fall out of the user interface specification requirements (if you have such a thing), I'd think about implementing it (or implementing the hooks) sooner rather than later.

1) retro-fitting it to something that's been architected to return complete pages will not necessarily be straightforward

2) it'll potentially impact the deployment pattern of your solution, in that it'll be serving up pages plus page fragments/objects, and those fragments will result in many more hits to your server (imagine the extra hits that your server would get if you introduced something like Google [Suggest](http://www.google.co.uk/webhp?hl=en&complete=1), where potentially every keypress could result in a new server request).

So you may not want to implement the Ajaxness immediately. But I would urge you to consider it (and if its required) sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 1):

Another argument for implementing Ajax early is that whenever you add any capability late in a project, you often have to tear down and rebuild some existing code or design to make it work.  When you plan for the feature from the beginning, there's a lot less recoding required.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion when it comes to ajax there are two camps. One camp wants to create this rich user experience with lots of neat UX goodies and will probably implement most of their sites features as ajax only. The other camp wants to add nice convenience features but the core of the project and most main features will be implemented server side. In the first camp where most of your features are going to be implemented in ajax I would work on the ajax early and work it into your design decision process upfront. For the second case I would implement all features server side and add the ajax afterwards to add some nice UX feel.

I remember reading early on with ajax, to implement your site like your user's browser did not have javascript, and then once all features are working add the ajax to improve the user experience. But since the early days of ajax Google has definitely pushed the envelope and a lot of people want to create these amazing rich user experiences on their websites with ajax. I've worked with a lot of people who really like to implement a lot of their features in ajax but few of them have had the chops to pull it off. I certainly don't have the chops myself and get very frustrated with buggy poorly tested features that look really cool... if you use them this certain way... cross your fingers. A lot of that has to do with testing, unit-testing is one thing, in browser testing is another and quite often I find myself working very hard just to get unit-tests in place let alone a whole in browser testing suite.

You have to decide what you want your user experience to be like, how ajax fits into those decision and then chose when to implement the ajax. Early for sites with major features implemented in ajax only, later for sites where ajax just addes UX sugar. That is my $0.02, I'm sure there is someone with the opposite opinion.